# responsive navigation bar using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

I have a navigation bar which I want to make responsive...when the user resizes the window and the width is less than particular value, the padding of `<a>` tag should change accordingly to accommodate all the `<li>` elements within the current window width...here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5kNgy/1/) 
in my example if we make width of widow less than 390px the last elements are coming down...I want to make such that when user goes resizing width of window when its less than 390px, the elements should start getting smaller, may be by changing their left and right padding....
so that it will become responsive...I am using jQuery....
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Please post your problem code, jsfiddle links will get downvoted: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle

Comment: I have only html tags and css...and using jsfiddle I can show you what I am doing

Comment: @vikasdevde the reason why we want you to post the code here in your post is so that it is easy to see, and future visitors will be able to access it. You can still post the JSFiddle as a supplement.

Comment: Sorry I should have been more explicit in saying that you can post jsfiddle links but you need to post the problem code as well.  If jsfiddle ever closes up shop this question will become invalid.

Comment: You are right. I will keep in mind next time I ask question...

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries in your CSS, jQuery is not necessary in this instance:

http://jsfiddle.net/5kNgy/2/

```
@media only screen and (min-width:0px) and (max-width:390px) {        
    .hor-menu ul li a {padding:2px;}
}
```

Comment: thanks...Lowkase...but is there a way using jquery, we can make a smooth transformation

Comment: Vikas, you should look into Twitter Boostrap. http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive You could end up reinventing the wheel here... Just a thought.

Comment: You can use CSS3 transitions in each media query to show effects when the new CSS is rendered.  CSS Media Queries is the best way to go about what you are asking for.  You can do this in jQuery, but it's going to get real sloppy the bigger your template and website get.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media (max-width: 390px) 
{
    .hor-menu ul li a { padding: 0 0 0 0 !important; }
}
```

I think this is what you are attempting to do?